# Measuring voltage across one end of a 50 ohm bias T and the other end is 50 ohm terminated

Tags: multimeter, voltage-measurement, adapter

I was looking to measure the output voltage from one of the PCBs using a multimeter. I connected the center of the 50 ohm T adapter to the DMM, one end of the T adapter to the output port of the DUT i.e the voltage we wanted to measure and the other end of the 50 ohm T adapter is terminated with 50 ohm load.  Why am I measuring only 0.33V on the DMM when I am supposed to measure 1.8V on the DMM? Can someone explain how the voltage drop occurs across the terminated load?

Comment: You might have source impedance. We don't know your system and impedances or voltages or terminations and why you expect to measure 1.8V, where would it come from?

Comment: What is the frequency of the signal? DMMs typically don't have large bandwidth.